# Create Agent Job

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to Create Agent Job In SQL Server

Comment: Too broad to explain in answer.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-transact-sql-job-step?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps listed below:

1. Start SQL Server Agent Service from your ssms
2. Expand SQL Server Agent
3. Right Click on Job select New Job
4. [Enter Your Job name and description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgHfZ.png)
5. [Select your database then  Write your Procedure or Query in command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV4iL.png)
6. [Select Scheduler and Schedule your job and set  time when you want to run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/On2cr.png)
7. You can execute your job manually -right click on your job an dclick on Start Job at Step